# How to automate file download in IE11

Tags: c#, asp.net, coded-ui-tests, mshtml

It is possible to automate file download and save in IE if its version is 8 or below using the following code:

```
AutomateWinWindow objfileWindow;
AutomateWinWindow objfileSaveAs;

objfileWindow = new AutomateWinWindow("File Download", "#32770", "1", "File Download", "");
CodedUI_Automation.AutomateWinButton.AutomateWinButtonMethod(objfileWindow, "Save", "File Download", "Click");

objfileSaveAs = new AutomateWinWindow("Save As", "#32770", "1", "Save As", "");
templatesourcefile = ManageSaveAsWindow(objfileSaveAs, TemplateInputPath, offeringID, "Excel");
```

But for the latest versions file download window is not coming. Its coming as a small pop up in the down without any name and id. It will be a great help if someone can help me in this.

Comment: We will need to see your code that works for 8 and below to be able to help you.

Comment: @TimFreese: I've added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have supplied does not look like plain coded ui to me.  Please also supply the class definitions for the AutomateWinWindow and ManageSaveAsWindow.

It is definitely possible to handle the save of a file.  I would recommend two things.

1. You can use the inspector from Coded UI tools to inspect the things you want to click on or manipulate.
2. You can use an inspector like the [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx) tool.

Normally I'd also recommend using record and play just to see what it figures out, but seems like record and play does not work for this (at least not on my machine).

Using the built in inspect tool, I can see that the notification toolbar has the following properties:

```
ControlType: ToolBar
TechnologyName: MSAA
Name: Notification
```

Using the navigation arrows in the inspector, you can move to children or sibling elements.

I was able to spy the UISaveSplitButton that can be used to save the file.

```
ControlType: SplitButton (important! not a button, but a split button)
TechnologyName: MSAA
Name: Save
```

Using a searching abstraction like [CodedUI Fluent](https://github.com/spelltwister/CodedUIFluentExtensions) (something I wrote, similar to [CUITe](https://github.com/icnocop/cuite)), it would look like:

```
WinToolBar notificationBar = browserWindow.Find<WinToolBar>(WinToolBar.PropertyNames.Name, "Notification", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);

WinSplitButton saveButton = notificationBar.Find<WinSplitButton>(WinButton.PropertyNames.Name, "Save", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);

saveButton.Click();
```

Using only CodedUI, it would look like this (I prefer the fluent searching syntax from the above abstraction, but for completeness):

```
WinToolBar notificationBar = new WinToolBar(browserWindow);
notificationBar.SearchProperties.Add(WinToolBar.PropertyNames.Name, "Notification", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);

WinSplitButton saveButton = new WinSplitButton(notificationBar);
saveButton.SearchProperties.Add(WinButton.PropertyNames.Name, "Save", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);

Mouse.Click(saveButton);
```

Comment: :I'm getting some error that WinSplitButton doesn't contain Click and also one more error that Find cannot be used with Type arguments

Comment: Yes, both of those are from a searching abstraction, but can be easily replaced with normal coded ui code.  Mouse.Click(saveButton) for instance.  I'll update to use only CodedUI

Comment: I'm getting System.Nullreference exception for Mouse click

Comment: You are getting a null reference somewhere else.  saveButtons is obviously not null.  Mouse.Click is a static method so what could be null?  Probably the browserWindow variable.  Are you passing in your browser window correctly?